# maven versions not seeing nexus deployments

Tags: java, maven, hudson, versions

We use Hudson and Nexus, and they work well apart from updating the versions of dependencies.

Following a release of a module, I want to upgrade some other module to look at the newly released version - say Project-A-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT depends on Project-B-1.0.0-SNASHOT, Project B gets released and becomes Project-B-1.0.0, I now want project A to depend on the released version of B.

For this we can use the maven versions plugin, and use versions:use-latest-releases. I do this on a local windows command line, with Hudson/Nexus being based over the network.  It seems that it will only work if I delete the my local repo's metadata.xml file (used by the versions plugin), as this is not up to date with the company repo recently released versions.

Am I doing something wrong here?  It is clear what maven will update by running versions:display-dependency-updates.  Is there a way to expire the metadata.xml or update it (setting the update setting on the repo to always not an option as this will slow things down)

Answer (score -1):

Maven has a snapshot checking policy. The default is to check for snapshot changes once a day.

try running `mvn -U versions:use-latest-releases` or `mvn --update-snapshots versions:use-latest-releases`

Comment: read for comprehension, the question is about going from `1.0-SNAPSHOT` to a full version `1.0` and updating all the projects that depend on the project that is moving to release being updated to have their dependencies in their `pom.xml` updated to `1.0` from `1.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Well, I think this may be along the right line, as it seems to force a refresh of metadata.xml from nexus (however, i seem to have to tell nexus to rebuild its metadata) so then the versions plugin seems to work.  I still have to confirm it works for upgrading a release version though (when I get to that scenario).